# Need assistance with Pygame and creating windows

Tags: pygame

For some reason, when I use the code below:

```
import pygame, sys

pygame.init()

def create_window():

    global window, window_height, window_width, window_title
    window_width, window_height = 1280, 720
    window_title = "The Adventure of Nate"
    pygame.display.set.caption(window_title)
    window = pygame.display.set_mode((window_width, window_height, pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUFF)

create_window()

isrunning = True

while isrunning == True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                isRunning = False

        window.fill(0, 0, 0)

        pygame.display.update()


pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

I get the following error:

> C:\Python3.6\python.exe "C:/Users/home/PycharmProjects/Basic RPG/Base
>   Game.py"   File "C:/Users/home/PycharmProjects/Basic RPG/Base
>   Game.py", line 16
>       create_window()
>                   ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

If anyone is experienced in the matter, can they help me correct my code.

(P.S: This is my first time coding without assistance, so sorry if my code is all over the place XD)

Comment: You didn't close parenthesis while calling `pygame.display.set_mode`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a `)` in the line `window = pygame.display.set_mode((window_width, window_height, pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUFF)`

It should be `window = pygame.display.set_mode((window_width, window_height), pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUFF)`